# some float values are not converting to int in pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
df['movieId']=df['movieId'].astype('int')
df.loc[92]['movieId']
```

The output from `df.loc[92]['movieId']` is 134368.0
But it should be 134368

I checked the dtype

`df.loc[92]['movieId'].dtype`

and it gives `dtype('float64')` but the other values have been converted to int.

Comment: Could you share a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can see what's going on? What does `df.dtypes` show for 'movieId'?

Answer (score 2):

Problem is in selecting:

```
df.loc[92]['movieId']
```

First select 92 index, what convert row to `Series` with floats, because some another `float` column(s).

Correct selecting is by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with index and column value:

```
df.loc[92, 'movieId']
```

**Sample**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'movieId':[1343680.0, 134369.0],
                   'col':[4,7.5]}, index=[92,95])
print (df)
    col    movieId
92  4.0  1343680.0
95  7.5   134369.0

df['movieId']=df['movieId'].astype('int')
print (df)
    col  movieId
92  4.0  1343680
95  7.5   134369

print (df.loc[92])
col              4.0
movieId    1343680.0
Name: 92, dtype: float64

print (df.loc[92]['movieId'])
1343680.0

print (df.loc[92, 'movieId'])
1343680
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using numpys `int64`

**Ex:**

```
import numpy as np
df['movieId']=df['movieId'].astype(np.int64)
```